# Why would we need void return type from methods in OOP languages?

Tags: c#, java, oop

It's not that I've started learning Java yesterday, but suddenly I thought, why would we ever use `void` methods, if we can return `this` instead? That way we can chain method calls on object and make the code more readable (I know that this approach is gaining popularity already, but mostly with immutable objects, and lets forget about *Java Beans* convention). The only case I think of `void` being required is static methods.

Comment: `this.Does().Not().Make().Code().More().Readable();`

Comment: IMO it's a matter of taste :-) `new Cake().make().bake().eat();` seems good to me.

Comment: I agree with Marc; the above sentence will force me to check if each of the methods is returning `this`, or if some of them return and act over other values (what happens if `more()` returns `AnotherInstanceNotReallyRelated`?). `this.does()` + `this.not()` + .... may be more length to write but avoids those errors.

Comment: @mattytommo again, it depends on the API; sometimes it might make sense for extension methods to be "fluent". Sometimes it might not. It isn't "because they are extension methods" - it is an aspect of *what they are*. To take a .NET example, LINQ extension methods are often (not always) "fluent" because LINQ expresses "composition", and "composition" is ideally suited to a "fluent" API.

Comment: In any case, static methods cannot return `this`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Presumably you will accept that some methods need to tell you something - some kind of return value. It seems artificial and obtuse that we would "return the value we want to return, unless we don't actually want to return anything, in which case we return `this` instead, unless it is a static method, in which case we return `void`".

How about:

- if it is appropriate to return something, then return it
- if if isn't, then don't
- (with some wriggle room for cases where a "fluent" API genuinely makes sense)

Also: think inheritance; if I have a virtual method `Foo()`, then the return type would have to be `Foo`'s declaring type:

```
public virtual SomeType Foo() {...}
```

Now imagine I subclass `SomeType`, with `Bar : SomeType` and have an instance of `Bar`:

```
Bar obj = new Bar();
obj.Foo().SomeOtherMethodOnBar(); // ERROR hey, where did my Bar go!?!?!
```

polymorphism does not respect fluent APIs.

As a final thought: think of all the "pop"s when you don't actually want to chain methods...

Comment: +1, worth noting as well how unmaintainable it can become when your chainable methods actually change things other than what you're chaining. SpAgHeTtI cOdE :)

Comment: I think the answer given is correct. I do, however, also feel that any general aversion against the chaining of methods per se is invalid. E.g. inspired by functional programming, concepts included such as immutable data structures and referential transparency, a "fluent" coding style can be both valid and clean.

Comment: @OskarLindberg hence my emphasis on "where a 'fluent' API genuinely makes sense". Yes, for some scenarios they can be great. In at least half of those scenarios, each fluent method-call actually returns a composed object, not the original object.